# Questions re: caching a jquery object when passing to a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Given that **$thisObj** is referenced multiple times in the function, would it be better practice to cache $(this) before passing it to myFunction($thisObj)?

```
function myFunction($thisObj) {
  alert($thisObj.html());
  alert($thisObj.html());
  alert($thisObj.html());
}
```

Which way should it be called?

```
myFunction($(this));
```

OR

```
var $obj = $(this);
myFunction($obj);
```

Or does it not matter because the object is already "cached" once it's passed to the function? This seems like a very fundamental question, but I spent a lot of time searching this topic without a clear answer.

Comment: Unless you are using `$obj` elsewhere after calling `myFunction`, I don't think it matters.

Comment: They are the same. I'd prefer the first one unless you are going to use `$obj` somewhere else in the calling code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't make a difference inside `myFunction()` since the value is only calculated once when the function is called and then stored in the `$thisObj` parameter variable. The conde in the function just uses the contents of `$thisObj`, it does not evaluate `$(this)` repeatedly.

So I would prefer to call the function as `myFunction($(this))` since it's more to the point without creating an unnecessary extra variable.

With the extra variable, somebody reading the code will wonder if that variable will be used again later on, making the code (slightly) harder to understand.